# Host website with AWS without using Route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have a new .com.br domain, and according to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/registrar-tld-list.html#com.br) AWS site I *can no longer use Route 53 to register new .com.br domains or transfer .com.br domains to Route 53*.

Does this effectively mean that I cannot host my website using AWS? If not, how would I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still host your web site with AWS, and you can even still host your DNS service on Route 53.

The list you linked to is a list of domains which you can (or cannot) *register* with Route 53 as a domain registrar.

Answer (score 4):

**Route 53 is *not* required to host a website in AWS nor is it required to have name resolution to a service in AWS**

Wherever you currently manage the DNS records for your domain will be fine. Just point them to the IP or host address of the AWS site/service you're connecting to.

Comment: I accepted Michael's answer because he distinguished between _register with Route 53_ and _using Route 53_, but I would just like to say that I liked your answer as well because you provide a solution to the problem. Since I cannot upvote anything I had to make this comment in stead.

Comment: Agreed, both are good answers. I use a standard registrar, CloudFlare for caching and DNS, and an EC2 server.